# Generics and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Given this situation:

```
class School 
{
    public void print(){}
}

class Grade extends School{}

class Student extends School{}
```

What is the difference between this

```
public <E extends School> void someMethod(E someObj) 
{
    //now we can pass any object that extends school 
    //and we have access to any methods that are in school
    someObj.print();

}
```

and this?

```
public void someMethod(School someObj)
{
    someObj.print();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious difference is that one is generic and the other is not.

And the other that know is that the generic one can capture the actual type of the argument. Of course it doesn't make any difference in this case. But imagine if you wanted the return type to be the exact type of the argument, then it would come into picture.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is no difference, because the type parameter is just used in one place as the type of a parameter. A type parameter is only necessary in more complicated cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference, `Generics` are used to provide type safety. Generics will let you see Compile-time bugs, for example, can be detected early on; you can use the compiler's error messages to figure out what the problem is and fix it, right then and there.

Here you are using *bounded type parameter* to the method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html